# Display taxonomy term content based on session

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am able to display the region based on IP using the below code:
if ($_SESSION['smart_ip']['location']['country_code'] == 'IN'): ?>

India content specific

Now I want to use a taxonomy term like India and display the content, whichever posted in India.

I want to print the nodes, which has term as India only if the above condition satisfies:
foreach ((array)$taxonomy as $item) print $item-> India

Answer (score 0):

If you have a catalog that allows you to identify the geographical location some session is associated with you could add an attribute 'search terms' to each entry in that catalog. That way once you identify the location in the catalog the session is associated with you have a list of search terms. You can then use these seach terms to filter a database query for all posts to get only those posts that contain one or all of the given search terms.

The list of search terms for the example india might start with `(India,Bhārat,Gaṇarājya,...)`...

Comment: Thank you, Arkascha. I am using this in Drupal. I have created taxonomy as Countries and terms as India, Australia etc.... When I am creating a new post, there is a option to select term as India , Australia etc. I want to display the content, which has term as India, if the user is browsing from India automatically in a block or page. Thank you.

Comment: Sure, I think I have a rough idea what you are trying to create. However I am afraid that it is not a good idea to rely on single questions you ask here to find people to tell you what to do. One the one hand this leads to you not learning how to create software architecture and on the other hand this is an extremely ineffective way to communicate. I got the impression that it might make sense for you to find a few fellows who like to help and communicate in an irc channel. This board is only effective for specific questions and problems. Not as a general advisory channel.